# Can data analytics be a basis for artificial intelligence?

Tags: bigdata, career

I'm very passionate about how computers can be made able to think intelligently and independently (in our favour, of course!). I'm currently studying Bachelors science of information technology at UTS (University of Technology:Sydney). I have two months before I start my second year, and have not yet been able to decide on which major should I select that can lead myself towards dedicated study of Artificial Intelligence (which I love with my life).

I have the following majors available:

- Internetworking and Applications
- Data Analytics
- (there are other two as well, but business oriented).

[Here](http://uts.edu.au) is the link to my subjects. I believe that being able to play with data is a sign of intelligence (I may be wrong too!). Will one of these subjects form me a good foundation for my further study in A.I.? Or should I jump into Engineering? Or Pure Science?

Comment: Please, provide us with the main (and just the main!) topics discussed in each subject. This would make your post self contained, instead of forcing others to flick through your course webpages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes related to Artificial Intelligence are typically taught in Computer Science departments. Looking at the [IT Project Subjects offered by your university](https://my.feit.uts.edu.au/pages/course/undergraduate/it_project_subjects), I suspect Data Analytics would indeed be more relevant to AI than Internetworking and Applications.

Looking at the courses offered by your department, the following likely involve aspects of AI:

- Image Processing and Pattern Recognition
- Intelligent Agents
- Building Intelligent Agents

For self-directed study in AI, I recommend starting with Russell & Norvig's essential textbook [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/).

As to what it will take to create a human-like strong AI, I recommend this collection of essays: [The Philosophy of Artificial Intelligence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198248547)... even though the material is getting a bit out-of-date by now.

Good luck!

Comment: I'd also take relevant classes from the [statistics](http://handbook.uts.edu.au/directory/maj01111.html) or [maths](http://handbook.uts.edu.au/directory/maj01110.html) [departments](http://handbook.uts.edu.au/directory/stm90681.html). And do buy that book Charlie recommended!